# O que fazer com uma pergunta que tem várias respostas que "deveriam ser edições"?

Tags: debate, respostas

Vejam essa pergunta abaixo:

[Imprimir divs separadas mas com o mesmo id](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227590/66203)

Eu fiz uma edição nessa pergunta e hoje resolvi ver o que tinha acontecido com a mesma.

[image: Pergunta]

Podem ver que tem uma resposta aceita e para *ajudar mais outras 3*. O problema é que essas outras 3 são do **MESMO** usuário.

- Como se deve proceder em tal situação?

Não que eu seja um *expert* no assunto, mas pelo que pude ver tem uma respostas com jQuery e outras 2 com Javascript, e ainda outra em HTML/CSS. Não seria melhor juntar as perguntas, transformá-las em edição de uma única resposta?

Talvez deixar um comentário para o AP das respostas fazer as edições? Ou até sinalizar como não é resposta? O que se deveria fazer?

**P.S**: Olhando um pouco mais, nenhuma das respostas explica o funcionamento dos códigos, são todas repostas "com códigos jogados". Todas estilo:

> Tente assim então:
>   Assim funciona tambem, mas precisa ter Jquery!:
>   Veja se da certo:

Comment: Oriente o autor que deve editar a resposta em um post só, caso as outras não tenham nada de tão diferente.

Comment: @Articuno, acredito que orientar seja a melhor opção, mas resolvi perguntar para ver ser se tinhamos algum outro *"posicionamento"*. E as respostas são semelhantes, diferentes maneiras de resolver um mesmo problema. Uma com jQuery, 2 com JS puro e uma outra que eu nem entendi o que é com HTML/CSS.

Comment: O mesmo autor fez isso [nesta pergunta também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227617/5878).

Comment: Nossa mais 2, tem que deixar um comentário logo, antes que *flood* o site com edições respostas @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Eu acho que respostas assim devem ser negativadas. É uma forma de "desincentivar" esse comportamento.

Comment: Acredito que sua opnião também seja válida. Já tinha votado contra elas @Renan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dê `flag` (Sinalize) em todas postagens explicando o problema, os moderadores estão para resolver estes tipos de problemas principalmente (creio eu).

Um detalhe importante se uma resposta tiver mais votos negativos (downvote) em uma resposta dependendo do seu nível no site será habilitado um link chamado <kbd>remover</kbd> (se tiver reputação/privilégio para isto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), ao clicar nele a postagem será "enviada" para a triagem na fila de analise, por exemplo:

> [image: votar para remover]

Comment: Esse link de remover que aparece em respostas depois do negativo é só pra quem tem 20k+ de rep