# Qual o uso da meta-tag "múltiplas-respostas"?

Tags: debate, meta-tags

Estive a explorar o meta e me deparei com [essa pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6254/64969). Isso me brotou uma semente de dúvida em uma pergunta que eu havia postado duas respostas distintas.

Fui atrás de abrir uma pergunta sobre a minha "*resposta específica*" (baseado na existência da [pergunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pergunta-espec%c3%adfica)), mas então não achei a [resposta-específica](/questions/tagged/resposta-espec%c3%adfica), e surpreendentemente para mim encontrei [múltiplas-respostas](/questions/tagged/m%c3%baltiplas-respostas). Então reparei que aquela [postagem que eu havia lido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6254/64969) era a única com essa meta-tag. E por enquanto essa meta-tag não tem orientação de uso.

- Devemos deixar ela sofrer `burnination`, editar a wiki de tag para por informações relevantes ou simplesmente ignorá-la?
- Se é o caso de por informações relevantes, quais seriam essas informações? Seria adequado ter uma pergunta/resposta canônica aqui no meta sobre as raras ocorrências em que há recomendação de se fazer respostas múltiplas?

Comment: Eu voto por burnination.

Comment: Não lembro se foi eu que criei, mas usei essa porque haviam múltiplas respostas na pergunta que você citou. Olhei no [so] e vi que tinham uma tag semelhante, então resolvi usá-la também aqui no [pt.so]. Por mim se o povo quiser *burnination*, que queime então (até porque nem temos o *burnination*).

Comment: Pessoal, acho uma ótima oportunidade de discutirmos a utilidade da tag, se as pessoas acharem útil é até legal para incentivar. Caso contrário removemos e a vida continua. De imediato deixo os parabéns pelo uso do Meta que ao meu ver vocês Stormwind e Jefferson tem feito muito bem. :D

Comment: Hoje é dia de prestação de contas @GuilhermeNascimento. Vou aproveitar o "ânimo que ainda tenho" (e são 10:20 da manhã) e responder tudo que tenho que explicar.